# ClientDataSet + FDQuery - Very Slow

Tags: delphi, firebird

My application get data in Firebird database with FDQuery:

```
  LQry.Close;
  
  LQry.sql.Clear;

  LQry.sql.Add('SELECT * FROM VENDA');
  LQry.Open;
```

And add this data in clientdataset:

```
LQry.First;
while not LQry.Eof do
begin
 cdsVendas.Append;
 cdsVendasid.AsString := LQry.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
 cdsVendas.Post;
 LQry.Next;
end;
```

I know if connect fdquery > dataProvider > clientDataSet, works better, but my clientdataset is not created in runtime, because I need some properties (Display label fields) and more fields in addition my query.

Comment: Infinite loops always take a lot of time.  Missing a `LQry.next;` in the code you posted.

Comment: It would be better to use a simple sql query to do what your infinite loop is trying to do - insert into vendas (id) select id from venda.

Comment: I fix my question. My original code have this 'LQry.Next;'. Thats not the problem.

Comment: Do you have DBGrids (or any other db-aware controls) connected to one or both datasets?  If so, do you use `DisableControls` & `EnableControls`?  If not, you should ...

Comment: @ReneSá and how many fields does you "real code" have ? Do you understand that `FieldByName('ID')` is rather slow function? String comparison with uppercasing + linear search through array, it is quadratic scaling (w.r.t. fields number and average name lenght). Make caching `TField` variables and call all `FieldByName` functions only once before the loop.

Comment: Actually make this in two steps, 1) populate `TList<record>` from the SQL query, 2) populate CDS from the said `TList<record>`. Then compare which of those steps is slow and which is not.

Comment: Thanks @Arioch'The. I 'm try make the proccess with Tlist<record>.

Comment: @ReneSá and move `FieldByName` outside the loop

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ClientDataset instead of a FDMemTable?

Answer (score 3):

Disable logchanges may improve performance.

cdsVendas.logchanges :=false